# Python tkinter how do you close a window as you create a new window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on an app in python where it goes from one window, asks for input, then opens a new window. How do I close the previous window when I open a new one? The user hits this button:

```
root = Tk()
Button(root, text ="No", command=partial(Plan.plan, root)).pack()
```

Then in the function, I try to open a new window and close the previous one with the variable "root" that I passed but that didn't work.

```
top = Toplevel()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: if you destroy the main window then the code will terminate

Comment: Try switching `Frame` inside main window instead of switching `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 0):

This is used to open new window without closing first one, just minimize first window

```
from tkinter import *


def open_new_win():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    root.wm_withdraw()
    top.mainloop()


root = Tk()
Button(root, text="No", command=open_new_win).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should not run multiple `mainloop()`.

Comment: But for running the main window, have to use it

Comment: Without `top.mainloop()`, the `top` window will still be shown.

Comment: @HardikJain `mainloop()` is not required for `Toplevel`.